# oracle flashback feature for tables of a specific user in a database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to implement a flashback feature in oracle 11g. I have successfully implemented it but it is not restricted to a single user instead, whenever I restore a flashback it affects all the tables/views for all the users. Is there some way to restrict the restoration to a particular user and avoiding the rest.

Example: I have a database `"db"` and there are 4 users `"a,b,c,d"` now, I want to restore the flashback such that it only affects user `"a"`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the command [`FLASHBACK TABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9012.htm#SQLRF01802) instead of `FLASHBACK DATABASE` to only affect specific tables.

For example:

```
create table table1(a number) enable row movement;
create table table2(a number) enable row movement;

--Wait one second.

flashback table jheller.table1, jheller.table2 to timestamp systimestamp - interval '1' second;
```

Keep in mind that table flashback uses UNDO, while database flashback uses flashback logs.  Table flashback depends on UNDO retention and is more picky about things like DDL.